# make alt for imageButton in yii

Tags: yii, imagebutton, alt

i want to put alt for the imageButton.
this is my code:

```
CHtml::imageButton($src.'flag.png', array('width'=>'40px', 'height'=>'40px','name'=>'fjfhjf' ,'alt'=>'dfffffffff'));
```

Comment: whats the current generated HTML?

Comment: there is no alt appears when the mouse being over the button

Comment: If you want the alt text as a crude tooltip in all browsers. Try adding a title attribute with the same text (as your alt attribute). Like this: `[...] 'alt'=>'some tooltip text', 'title' => 'some tooltip text' [...]`

Comment: @TommyBravo , its work fine with `'title'`, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is use `title` attribute in the html options array.